# AS3: Perform action in intervals based on incrementing int

Tags: actionscript-3

So as not to complicate my question, I won't involve the context, but basically let's say I have a variable:

```
var foo:int;
```

And 'foo' is constantly incrementing, how would I be able to perform a function every 300 increments (300,600,900, etc) of 'foo'?

Cheers

EDIT: Also worth mentioning, the number can occasionally skip numbers as it is a rounded version of a decimal number that is incrementing

Answer (score 0):

What about making it a private variable and only acces it using these accessor methods:

```
function getFoo():int {
    return foo;
}

function setFoo(newFoo:int):void {
    if (newFoo % 300 > foo % 300) performAction();
    foo = newFoo;
}
```

You could also add convenience methods like `incrementFoo(increment:int)` of course.

Sorry for possible syntax errors. I haven't used AS3 for quite a while.

Comment: Cheers, actually sorted it out not long after writing this using a similar method!